# I want to get result of each checkbox in PHP POST by ajax on real time checkbox selection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, checkbox

I want to get result of each checkbox in PHP POST by ajax on real time checkbox selection

```js
function showValues() {
  var str = $("form").serialize();
  $("#results").text(str);
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", showValues);
showValues();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check3" id="ch3">
  <label for="ch2">check3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check4" id="ch4">
  <label for="ch2">check4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check5" id="ch5">
  <label for="ch2">check5</label>
</form>

<tt id="results"></tt>
```

Comment: What is your question, does something not work as expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where is your `Ajax` / `PHP` code?

Comment: This is half program. Actually i need to get result in php post. It can be a string or individual variables.

Comment: You are still not asking an actual question. Please note that a mere _“I need”_, is not considered one here. Please go read [ask].